# Cannot access 'API_URL' before initialization

Tags: reactjs, rest, http

I have an HTTP class for REST methods:

```
import { getQueryString } from './utils';
import { API_URL } from './api';
import { defaultHeaders } from './api/consts';



export default class Http {
  service = {};

  constructor(apiUrl) {
    this.apiUrl = apiUrl;
    const service = axios.create({ baseURL: this.apiUrl });
    .....
    this.service = service;
    });
  }

 

  get(path, query, headers = {}) {
    const fullPath = query ? `${path}?${getQueryString(query)}` : path;
    return this.service
      .get(fullPath, headers)
      .then((response) => response)
      .catch((error) => Promise.reject(error));
  }


  post(path, payload) {
    return this.service
      .request({
        method: 'POST',
        url: path,
        withCredentials: true,
        data: payload ? JSON.stringify(payload) : {},
      })
      .then((response) => response)
      .catch((error) => Promise.reject(error));
  }

   .....
}
```

API_URL is in `.env` file:

```
export const API_URL = `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}`;
```

The idea is to use it with different API URLs. For example:

```
const API_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8081'
export const http1 = new Http(API_URL);

const API_URL2 = 'http://127.0.0.1:8082'
export const http2 = new Http(API_URL2);
```

And usage:

`http1.get('someurl.com')` etc.

But I am getting this error:

```
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'API_URL' before initialization
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `import { API_URL } from './api';` What are the contents of this file

Comment: it's  in .env file: export const API_URL = `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}`;

Comment: Try changing `APP_URL` to `APP_URL1`. Maybe conflict because of same const declaration.